# Definition of congruence subgroup of $\text{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$

Tags: definition, modular-forms, general-linear-group

In Diamond and Shurman's book on modular forms, they define

> **Definition 1.2.1.** A subgroup $\Gamma$ of $\text{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$ is a **congruence subgroup** if $\Gamma(N)\subset \Gamma$ for some $N\in\mathbf{Z}^+$, in which case $\Gamma$ is a congruence subgroup of **level** $N$.

Clearly, $\Gamma(N)\subset \text{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$ for every $N$. Does that make $\text{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$ a congruence subgroup of level $N$ for every $N$, or are we choosing a minimum $N$ for which the definition is satisfied, i.e. $\text{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$ is level $1$ only.

Comment: Yes that's true, although in practice, when we say $\Gamma$ has level $N$, we typically mean minimal level $N$. This type of thing becomes important later in the book when you discuss newforms: if $f$ is a modular form of level $1$, then $f$ is also a modular form of level $N$ for every $N$. But the "important" modular forms are those forms that you "first see" at level $N$.